# PHPList settings to send 50,000 emails per hour

Tags: email, phplist

I have a VPS with 2GB with cPanel/WHM

Installed PHPList Latest Version

Create a batch of 2000 list

PHPList Settings as following

```
define('USE_DOMAIN_THROTTLE',0.2);
define('DOMAIN_BATCH_SIZE',800);
define('DOMAIN_BATCH_PERIOD',120);
```

Still it's not sending emails more than 300 taking too much time

```
A process for this page is already running and it was still alive 532 seconds ago
Sleeping for 20 seconds, aborting will quit
A process for this page is already running and it was still alive 593 seconds ago
Sleeping for 20 seconds, aborting will quit
Started
Processing has started, 1 message(s) to process.
Please leave this window open. You have batch processing enabled, so it will reload
several times to send the messages. Reports will be sent by email to 
xxx@yahoo.com
Processing message 79
Looking for subscribers
Found them: 1392 to process
Sending in batches of 10000 emails
```

Comment: Please help me on https://superuser.com/questions/1205929/not-able-to-send-mail-using-phplist about SMTP setting

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the phplist on my vps having 1gb ram, 20gb hdd, 1 core, ubuntu (lamp, sendmail) and it is running as I answer this. I did not enabled/tweaked any of the above settings. Left as it is. Well there are some issues if the batch size is more than 1000 mails and process q is taking some time if we do not enable domain throttling. Check processing queue in config_extended.php file and it might help in q processing better as they say.
Also check 
http://docs.phplist.com/ProcessQueueInfo.html

I also suggest - using phplist with an smtp server (installed on the same vps) or smtp relay. That gives you better mail sending.

might help you

Good Luck

Following are copied from the process...

```
Started
Processing has started,
One campaign to process.
Please leave this window open. phpList will process your queue until all messages have been sent. This may take a while
Report of processing will be sent by email
Processing message 8
Looking for subscribers
Found them: 6594 to process
Sending in batches of 1000 emails
Processing batch of: 1000
Size of HTML email: 4Kb
Processed 188 out of 6594 subscribers
Script stage: 5
187 messages sent in 60.05 seconds (11210 msgs/hr)
Finished this run
Less than batch size were sent, so reloading imminently
This batch will be 923 emails, because in the last 30 seconds 77 emails were sent
Processing batch of: 923
Size of HTML email: 4Kb
Processed 183 out of 6407 subscribers
Script stage: 5
182 messages sent in 60.07 seconds (10906 msgs/hr)
Finished this run
Less than batch size were sent, so reloading imminently
```

Comment: Please help me on https://superuser.com/questions/1205929/not-able-to-send-mail-using-phplist about SMTP setting